# validating a postfix with too many operators

Tags: python, validation

I am evaluating a postfix expression and I need it to say that the expression cannot be evaluated if there are too many operators one after the other. I understand there will be nothing in the stack so it cannot be evaluated but I don't know how to add it in my code.

I have only added here the code that I feel is necessary. If the code could be kept relatively similar that would be great.

edit: it is now just saying that anything cannot be evaluated

```py
def process(testline,count):
    k=[]

    for i in range(0,len(testline),1): 
        if(testline[i].isdigit() == True): 
            k.append(float(testline[i]))

        else:
            try:
                x = j.pop()
                y = j.pop()
            except IndexError:
                break

        if (testline[i]=='*'): 
            ans = x * y
            k.append(ans)

        elif (testline[i]=='+'):
            ans = x + y
            k.append(ans)

        elif (testline[i]=='-'):
            ans = x - y
            k.append(ans)

        elif (testline[i]=='/'):
            ans = x / y
            k.append(ans)

        else:
            print("Line",count,"is not able to be evaluated")
            return

    if len(k) != 1:
        print("Line",count,"is not able to be evaluated")
    else:
        print ('Line',count,'result is',k[0])
        return

    print('Line',count,'result is',k[0])
```

Right now, the output is:

```
    Line 1 is not able to be evaluated
    Line 2 is not able to be evaluated
    Line 3 is not able to be evaluated
    Line 4 is not able to be evaluated
```

The input is:

```
    295+*3-
    61*7-4*
    61*79-15*
    6a*7-b*
    623-+*-1
```

Comment: You check if the stack is empty. If it is, you report this. So `if not k`.

Comment: ...I'd say `if len(k) < 2`, as only a single available element on the stack is just as problematic.

Comment: I see you updated your code.  The problem with it now is that you need to indent the code after the `else` clause that you added so that the math operations are inside that `else`.  You only want the math ops to happen if you've popped values off of the stack to be operated on.

Answer (score 0):

You could move your `pop`s to the start of the iteration and surround with `try/except` to check that you can pop:

```py
for i in range(0,len(testline),1): 
    if(testline[i].isdigit() == True): 
        k.append(float(testline[i]))

    else:
        try:
            x = k.pop()
            y = k.pop()
        except IndexError:
            break

        if (testline[i]=='*'): 
            ans = x * y
            k.append(ans)

        elif (testline[i]=='+'):
            ans = x + y
            k.append(ans)

        elif (testline[i]=='-'):
            ans = x - y
            k.append(ans)

        elif (testline[i]=='/'):
            ans = x / y
            k.append(ans)

        else:
            print("Line",count,"is not able to be evaluated")
            return
```

To make it more robust and don't need to add those extra `appends` I will do:

```py
operators = {'*': lambda x ,y: x * y,
             '/': lambda x, y: x / y,
             '+': lambda x, y: x + y,
             '-': lambda x, y: x - y}

for c in testline:
    if c.isdigit(): 
        k.append(float(c))

    elif c in operators:
        try:
            x = k.pop()
            y = k.pop()
        except IndexError:
            break
        ans = operators[c](x, y)
        k.append(ans)

    else:
        print("Line",count,"is not able to be evaluated")
        return
```

**EDIT:** even simpler:

```py
operators = {'*': lambda x ,y: x * y,
             '/': lambda x, y: x / y,
             '+': lambda x, y: x + y,
             '-': lambda x, y: x - y}

for c in testline:
    if c.isdigit(): 
        k.append(float(c))

    else:
        try:
            x = k.pop()
            y = k.pop()
            ans = operators[c](x, y)
            k.append(ans)
        except IndexError:  # Couldn't pop... (empty stack)
            break
        except KeyError:  # char is not a digit and not an operator
            print("Line",count,"is not able to be evaluated")
            return
```

Comment: I totally agree with the idea of your advice here.  And I guess it's seen as Pythonic to use a try/except in this way, unlike some other languages where try/catch is supposed to be avoided as a way to check user input.  I'll just point out, FWIW, that instead of a try/except, the code could just test for `len(k) < 2` to preflight that enough arguments exist to perform the requested operation.

Comment: There's a problem with your first version.  You've changed the logic such that the two pops are done even if the first `if` clause is true.  You really want an outer `if/else` block, where you only do the pops if the first test fails.

Comment: @Steve As for your first comment: in my first version I tried to do it closely to the OP code, so your suggested test is not valid since an empty stack is also OK for the first case. In my second solution I guess you're right but I guess also it saves some PCU by not checking for `len` and simply running the code and handling the Exception. As I learned, the pythonic way is *ask for forgivness, not permission*. For your second comment, note that I appended those values back. Of course is a little dumb, but I wanted to avoid too many nested conditions...

Comment: Anyway, @Steve I changed the first solution according to your comment. Looks better... :)

Comment: cool.  looks better.  won't push the point, but think about what your original version would have done in the case of the first digit of input.

Comment: I don't see any problem @Steve. Just as a comment: I don't "support" the first version. Simply used it because the OP asked the code to stay the same. That's why I gave my code as an alternative...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I changed it and moved my pops to the start of the iteration but now it is saying that all of the lines are not able to be evaluated. I would use the more robust code but I do need the code to stay the same so would you know how to fix that problem

Comment: @juni1358, yes. you simply didn't copy it correctly... You didn't keep the correct indentations so now even when there is a digit, the final else block will also execute...

Answer (score 0):

Per the OP's desire to keep the original code as unchanged as possible, here's a version of the code that works with the most minimal of changes.  The primary change, which is what the OP is asking about specifically, is to add checks for an inadequate number of operands before each arithmetic operation.  This code also has the order of operands in calculations reversed where necessary:

```
def process(testline,count):

    k=[]

    for i in range(0,len(testline),1):
        if(testline[i].isdigit() == True):
            k.append(float(testline[i]))

        elif (testline[i]=='*'):
            if len(k) < 2:
                print("Line", count, "is not able to be evaluated. not enough operands")
                return
            x = k.pop()
            y = k.pop()
            ans = x * y
            k.append(ans)

        elif (testline[i]=='+'):
            if len(k) < 2:
                print("Line", count, "is not able to be evaluated. not enough operands")
                return
            x = k.pop()
            y = k.pop()
            ans = x + y
            k.append(ans)

        elif (testline[i]=='-'):
            if len(k) < 2:
                print("Line", count, "is not able to be evaluated. not enough operands")
                return
            x = k.pop()
            y = k.pop()
            ans = y - x    # << reversed operands
            k.append(ans)

        elif (testline[i]=='/'):
            if len(k) < 2:
                print("Line", count, "is not able to be evaluated. not enough operands")
                return
            x = k.pop()
            y = k.pop()
            ans = y / x   # << reversed operands
            k.append(ans)

        else:
            print("Line",count,"is not able to be evaluated")
            return

    if len(k) != 1:
        print("Line",count,"is not able to be evaluated")
        return

    print('Line',count,'result is',k[0])
```

With this test code:

```
lines = [
    '295+*3-',
    '61*7-4*',
    '61*79-15*',
    '6a*7-b*',
    '(-1)*2',
    '623-+*-1',
]

for i in range(len(lines)):
    process(lines[i], i + 1)
```

Resulting output is:

```
('Line', 1, 'result is', 25.0)
('Line', 2, 'result is', -4.0)
('Line', 3, 'is not able to be evaluated')
('Line', 4, 'is not able to be evaluated')
('Line', 5, 'is not able to be evaluated')
('Line', 6, 'is not able to be evaluated. not enough operands')
```

Comment: I understand that my code is not the best as I am still new to coding. I will take on your changes for future use but in the meantime is there any way my problem can be added to the code I currently have?

Comment: I have updated my code but it's not giving the correct output

Comment: I just changed my answer to hopefully give you what you want...the most minimal of changes that answers your question and also gets your code functioning correctly.  You were really close on all of this.

Comment: @juni1358 as I said before, if you are new to python, I would suggest starting off with simpler projects and going up gradually to get all the basics. I also don't understand why you are against learning and improving your code. That is the way to get better, change your code and make sure you understand each line, and your next project will be a few tens of lines shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version, which is much like @Tomrikoo's second, but provides a complete answer and addresses a few additional problems with the original code.  This code prints either the result or an error in all cases, and deals with the final state in both the case of a valid answer or an invalid stack condition (more than one item on the stack).  Also, I reversed the order of application of the operands to be correct (I assume that '42/' should produce 2 rather than 0.5 like all my HP calculators would):

```
def process(testline, count):

    operations = {
        '+': lambda x, y: y + x,
        '-': lambda x, y: y - x,
        '*': lambda x, y: y * x,
        '/': lambda x, y: y / x,
    }

    k = []

    for c in testline:

        if c.isdigit():
            k.append(float(c))

        elif c in operations:
            if len(k) < 2:
                print("Line {}: bad expression '{}' (not enough operands)".format(count, testline))
                return
            k.append(operations[c](k.pop(), k.pop()))

        else:
            print("Line {}: unexpected character '{}' in expression '{}'".format(count, c, testline))
            return

    if len(k) != 1:
        print("Line {}: bad expression '{}' (too many operands)".format(count, testline))
    else:
        print("Line {}: Result: '{}' = {}".format(count, testline, k[0]))


lines = [
    '295+*3-',
    '61*7-4*',
    '61*79-15*',
    '6a*7-b*',
    '(-1)*2',
    '623-+*-1',
]

for i in range(len(lines)):
    process(lines[i], i + 1)
```

Output:

```
Line 1: Result: '295+*3-' = 25.0
Line 2: Result: '61*7-4*' = -4.0
Line 3: bad expression '61*79-15*' (too many operands)
Line 4: unexpected character 'a' in expression '6a*7-b*'
Line 5: unexpected character '(' in expression '(-1)*2'
Line 6: bad expression '623-+*-1' (not enough operands)
```